# addEventListener to button to change the color of text in the button whet user click

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, textcolor

my code is not working. I'm creating a variable then add event listener to it

```
btnColor=document.getElementById("first");
btnColor.addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
```

then I create a function that change the btn text color to red, if it's bg color is transparent

```
let changeBtnColor = (btnColor) => {
  if (btnColor.style.backgroundColor == "trasnsparent") btnColor.style.color = "red";
}
```

and html code

```
<button type="button" class="first_text" id="first" onclick="changeBtnColor()">text</button>
```

Comment: debug it... my guess is the `backgroundColor` is not transparent. `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: maybe just a typo in **trasnsparent**.... try change it to **transparent**

Comment: This is misspelled -> "trasnsparent"
It should be "transparent"

Comment: When you add an event listener, it passes the event, not the element you're adding the listener to, so you'll want to define `changeBtnColor = (e) => {e.currentTarget...}`

Answer (score 0):

You are saying this function needs to have `btnColor` passed in.

```
let changeBtnColor = (btnColor) => {
  if (btnColor.style.backgroundColor == "trasnsparent") btnColor.style.color = "red";
}
```

In the inline `onclick="changeBtnColor()"` you do not pass in the button reference.

In the addEventListener `btnColor` is the event object.

Next issue is `trasnsparent` is not `transparent`

So with addEventListener you want to use currentTarget

```js
const changeBtnColor = (event) => {
  const btn = event.currentTarget;
  console.log(btn);
  console.log(btn.style.backgroundColor);
  if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "transparent") btn.style.color = "red";
}

const btnColor=document.getElementById("first");
btnColor.addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
```

```html
<button id="first" style="background-color:transparent">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- don't use HTML inline `on`* handlers like `onclick`
- place your function initialization up in the script (before calling it)
- don't check for `"transparent"` (browsers returned value might differ) - instead negate the color you're expecting it to be (`"red"`)

```js
const btnColor = document.getElementById("first");

// Bring on top, otherwise you'll get:
// Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'changeBtnColor' before initialization
const changeBtnColor = (evt) => {
  // console.log(evt) // that's your event, not the element!
  if (btnColor.style.backgroundColor !== "red") btnColor.style.color = "red";
};

btnColor.addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="first_text" id="first">text</button>
```

Since using Element.style should be discouraged whenever possible, it's a better idea to set the styles in CSS and use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) in JS :

```js
const btnColor = document.getElementById("first");

const changeBtnColor = (evt) => {
  btnColor.classList.add("red");
  // or use:
  // btnColor.classList.toggle("red");
};

btnColor.addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="first_text" id="first">text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `changeBtnColor` in two different places and it is wrong for both of them.

---

> ```
> let changeBtnColor = (btnColor) => {
> ```

Your function expects a button element to be passed to it as an argument.

---

> ```
> btnColor.addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
> ```

When you bind it as an event listener, the argument passed into it is [a `MostEvent` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

You can extract the button from it using [the `target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) or [the `currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

When you are binding to an element directly, `currentTarget` is safer as it will get the element to which the event is bound rather than the one that is actually clicked on. In this particular case, since the button only contains text (i.e. no other elements) they will always be the same.

If you were using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) then you would need to use `target` and combine it with something like [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to see if the element clicked was either the one you wanted or a descendent of it.

```
let changeBtnColor = (event) => {
    const btnColor = event.currentTarget;
    if (btnColor.style // etc
```

---

> ```
>  onclick="changeBtnColor()"
> ```

You call it again here, only this time you don't pass any argument to it at all.

Don't use `onclick` attributes. It's the 21st century now.

---

Then you have a second problem:

> ```
> btnColor.style.backgroundColor == "trasnsparent")
> ```

This will never be true because:

- You misspelt *transparent*
- Nothing ever sets the inline style to `transparent` (and `style` accesses the inline style, not the computed style).
- The default background colour for buttons isn't transparent anyway

In general, when dealing with style in JS, it's usually a good idea to modify the classes applied to the element and style them with CSS.

```js
const changeBtnColor = (event) => {
  const btn = event.currentTarget;
  btn.classList.toggle('example_class');
}

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', changeBtnColor);
```

```css
.example_class {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="first_text" id="first">text</button>
```